# Microsoft Excel - Live Updating Sheets Across Two MS Excel Instances / Sessions

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, multiple-monitors

Here is what I need to accomplish and I do not know how to get it done.  In essence I will have two separate MS Excel Files.  Call one DATAENTRY.XLSX and call the other DATADISPLAY.XLSX.  As information is entered into DATAENTRY.XSXL it updates graphs and information for a chart display on DATADISPLAY.XSLX.  So forumlas from one go to the other.

I need to figure out how to open each one in its OWN MS EXCEL INSTANCE (not in the same session).  Then, I need to be able to enter data into DATAENTRY.XLSX, and after information is entered, data from that spreadsheet file in INSTANCE 1 of MS Excel is used to update graphs/charts on DATADISPLAY.XSLX.

It does not have to be true "real-time" but that is preferred.  If I hit the ENTER Key in one document I'd like to see the update reflected on the other.  Worst-case scenario, I update information in DATAENTRY.XSLX and hit SAVE and once it SAVES it updates on the other.

Is there a way to accomplish this?  The reason for this setup has to do with keeping a graph/chart information up and visible for a WEB-EX type presentation, while I update information as I get it on the other.  This seems to be the only way I can get it to work via WEB-EX software and a dual monitor display, I just don't know how to link the files and allow them to update each other in seperate MS Excel instances.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you can't open two seperate excel documents on its own excel instance the only solution I found was to go to menu=> excel options=>advanced=>general=> change the setting of ignore other applications that use DDE.

This worked for me but when I changed it I had trouble opening documents, I could only open them through Excel=> open. Hope this doesn't happen to you.

And about the live updating.. The best thing I can come up with is using Windows Live Mesh or Dropbox. The files would update almost instantly after pressing "save". But you would have to re-open the other document...

Comment: The problem is, I don't want to open two files in a single Excel instance.  That doesn't help me due to the way the WebEx software works and dual monitors.  I need two instances of excel, with two different files, that link and update each other.  I'll look into that Live Mesh and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing a similar thing as you, where I have live sales results being displayed on the sales floor. As a sale is made the value is entered on to a spread sheet then the value is displayed on a screen on the sales floor.

How I achieved this, is to use the save as a web page option in excel, and saved this file to a shared directory, then the computer thats displaying the page open that file in a web browser, then you make the web browser auto refresh at your desired period of time(you may have to download a plug-in for that). the downside, is whoever is updating the spread sheet must remember to save each time they enter the data. Trying to figure away of getting the Auto save function to do this, but haven't yet.

Hope that helps